# how to check whether user has filled all element in a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
<textarea questn-id="123" />
<td questn-id="234"/>
```

I have quest-id of all textarea and td in list of string. How can I check if the textarea and td are filled in c#.

I have got the quest-id of all element using htmlagility pack and stored it in list of string now I want to see whether all the fields are full or empty. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: I don't understand your design. how textarea could be out of td ?

Answer (score 1):

As they said, you will have to add runat="server" to the elements
And you can search them in server side with linq:

```
var controls = Page.Controls.OfType<WebControl>().Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Attributes["questn-id"]));
```

Then you will have the controls that doesnt have the questn-id filled

Answer (score 0):

If your markup was this:

```
<textarea questn-id="123" id="txtarea" runat="server" />
<td questn-id="234" id="tdId" runat="server" />
```

You can do this:

```
if(txtarea.Value == "")
{
  // it is empty
}
else{
 // it is not empty. It has some value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check in codebehind then **add `runat="server"` for element textarea and access it by id**.

```
<textarea questn-id="123" id="txtarea" runat="server" />

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtarea.Text))
{
   Console.WriteLine("textarea is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I ran some VB code through a converter and changed as applicable.  So this may not be syntacticly correct, but you should get an idea on how to use the HtmlAgilityPack.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(stringContainingYourHtml);

foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode txt in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//textarea")) {
    if ((txt.Attributes("questn-id") != null) && ! String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Attributes("questn-id").Value) {
        string txtVal = txt.Attributes("questn-id").Value.ToLower();
        // do whatever you want to do for validation here.

}
```

}